# Checkerboard pattern without x and y (purely based on index)

Tags: algorithm, performance, optimization

Is there a way to generate a checkerboard pattern without using nested for loops and without using x and y?

I'm sure this has already been done before, but I couldn't find it in the ~15mins I was looking for it.

Currently I have this function that generates the pattern first extracting x and y:

```rust
fn get_bg_color_of(idx: usize) -> &'static str {
    const BG_BLACK: &str = "\u{001b}[48;5;126m";
    const BG_WHITE: &str = "\u{001b}[48;5;145m";

    let x = idx % Board::WIDTH;
    let y = idx / Board::WIDTH;

    let is_even_row = y % 2 == 0;
    let is_even_column = x % 2 == 0;

    if is_even_row && is_even_column || !is_even_row && !is_even_column {
        return BG_WHITE;
    }

    BG_BLACK
}
```

Is there a simpler way to do this? If yes, please also explain how and why, I like to know what's happening in my code :)

Comment: This is pretty much the simplest way, unless WIDTH is guaranteed to be odd.

Comment: @MattTimmermans I mean it's a chess board, so it's always 8 (that's also why the code worked before you edited it, both `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT` would always be 8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If WIDTH is even, then you need to separate x and y.  You can write that shorter, though:

```
fn get_bg_color_of(idx: usize) -> &'static str {
    const BG_BLACK: &str = "\u{001b}[48;5;126m";
    const BG_WHITE: &str = "\u{001b}[48;5;145m";

    if ( (idx + (idx/Board::WIDTH)) % 2 == 0 ) {
        return BG_WHITE;
    }
    return BG_BLACK;
}
```

Note that this doesn't work if WIDTH is odd.  In that case, you can just do:

```
    if ( idx % 2 == 0 ) {
        return BG_WHITE;
    }
}
```

If you need to handle both cases, then:

```
    if ( ((idx%Board::WIDTH) + (idx/Board::WIDTH)) % 2 == 0 ) {
        return BG_WHITE;
    }
```